# .NET library which can convert .ttf fonts to .woff

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a .NET library which can convert .ttf to .woff.

I'm currently manually converting my fonts with this website: https://andrewsun.com/tools/woffer-woff-font-converter/

Comment: are you sure this exists in .NET? Seems really specific for a library

Comment: Well you could use https://github.com/google/zopfli and call that from C# if you want to. May be hard but it's possible...

Comment: @diomonogatari More so an existing open source font library which could be modified to support such a thing.

Comment: I'm think I'm going to write a C# wrapper for ttf2woff. It seems to fit my needs nicely. I'm still open to other options. http://wizard.ae.krakow.pl/%7Ejb/ttf2woff/